# Makefile for avr-gcc "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, makefile, i2c

I'm new to makefile, and I tried to modify one I had by a teacher.

My goal is to link "i2cMaster.S" so I did this :

```
export CC = avr-gcc

export MCU = atmega328p
export TARGET_ARCH = -mmcu=$(MCU)

export CFLAGS =  -Wall -I. -DF_CPU=16000000 -Os #-g
export LDFLAGS = -g $(TARGET_ARCH) -lm -Wl,--gc-sections #  -Os


TARGET = main
TERM = /dev/ttyUSB0
CPPFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU)
PGID = arduino
PGMER = -c $(PGID) -b 57600 -P $(TERM)
PGMERISP = -c $(PGID) -b 115200 -P $(TERM)
ARVDUDECONF= -C /usr/local/arduino/arduino-0022/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf
export DUDE = /usr/bin/avrdude -F -v -p $(MCU) $(AVRDUDECONF)

C_SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
A_SRC = i2cmaster.S
OBJS = $(C_SRC:.c=.o) $(A_SRC:.S=.o)


all: $(TARGET).hex


clean:
    rm -f *.o

%.o:%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(@F)

%.o:%.S
    $(CC) -S $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(@F)

%.elf: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%hex: %.elf
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex
    avr-objcopy -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex $(TARGET).elf eeprom.hex

upload: $(TARGET).hex
    stty -F $(TERM) hupcl # reset
    $(DUDE) $(PGMER) -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex
#   $(DUDE) $(PGMERISP) -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex

size: $(TARGET).elf
    avr-size --format=avr --mcu=$(MCU) $(TARGET).elf
```

I added the `%.o:%.S` target, but it seems not to work. When I call `make all`, I have the following error :

```
avr-gcc: error: i2cmaster.o: No such file or directory.
```

I think the error is pretty obvious, bit I can't find out where it comes from.

Comment: Please show the actual compile lines and link line before you get this error, not just the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your command to assemble "i2cmaster.S" does not assemble, because you use the option `-S`:

```
%.o:%.S
    $(CC) -S $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(@F)
```

Instead use the option `-c`:

```
%.o:%.S
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(@F)
```

Please call GCC to help you:

```
gcc --help
```

And it will tell:

```
-c    Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.
-S    Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble.
```